# How to get SubscribeOn flatMap operator for iOS 13?

Tags: swift, ios13, combine

This code does not compile on iOS 13 because flatMap is available only in iOS 14. How to extend SubscribeOn to have flatMap operator?

```
func f1(_ value: Int) -> Future<Int, Error> {
    Future { promise in
        print("\(Thread.current): f1() value = \(value)")
        promise(.success(value + 1))
    }
}

func f2(_ value: Int) -> Future<Int, Error> {
    Future { promise in
        print("\(Thread.current): f2() value = \(value)")
        promise(.success(value + 1))
    }
}

let a1 = Just(0)
    .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global())
    .flatMap(f1)
    .flatMap(f2)
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink { _ in
        print("\(Thread.current): completed")
    } receiveValue: { value in
        print("\(Thread.current): sink() value = \(value)")
    }
```

UPDATE
Here is how my solution looks like now:

```
extension Publishers.SubscribeOn {
    func myFlatMap<P>(_ transform: @escaping (Self.Output) -> P) -> Publishers.FlatMap<P, Publishers.SetFailureType<Self, P.Failure>> where P: Publisher {
        Publishers.FlatMap<P, Publishers.SetFailureType<Self, P.Failure>>(
            upstream: Publishers.SetFailureType<Self, P.Failure>(upstream: self),
            maxPublishers: .unlimited,
            transform: transform
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is **a** `flatMap` operator available in iOS 13, but there are **more** `flatMap` operators available in iOS 14.

Specifically, [the only `flatMap` operator available in iOS 13](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/flatmap(maxpublishers:_:)-3k7z5) requires that the upstream publisher (in your example, `Just<Int>`) and the inner publisher (in your example, `Future<Int, Error>`) have the same `Failure` type. But `Just<Int>.Failure` is `Never`, while `Future<Int, Error>.Failure` is `Error`.

In iOS 14, there are three extra overloads of `flatMap` for special treatment of three cases:

- [when the upstream `Failure` type is `Never`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/flatmap(maxpublishers:_:)-qxf),
- [when the inner `Failure` type is `Never`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/flatmap(maxpublishers:_:)-4of8w),
- and [when both the upstream `Failure` and the inner `Failure` are `Never`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/flatmap(maxpublishers:_:)-hyb0).

Your example code falls into the first special case (upstream `Failure` is `Never`), so it compiles for iOS 14 but not for iOS 13.

You can work around the problem by explicitly transforming your `Just` with a `setFailureType` operator:

```
let a1 = Just(0)
    .setFailureType(to: Error.self)
    .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global())
    .flatMap(f1)
    .flatMap(f2)
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink { _ in
        print("\(Thread.current): completed")
    } receiveValue: { value in
        print("\(Thread.current): sink() value = \(value)")
    }
```

Alternatively, you can use a `Result.Publisher` to start out with the necessary `Failure` type of `Error`. Swift should even be able to deduce it for you:

```
let a1 = Result.success(0).publisher
    .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global())
    .flatMap(f1)
    .flatMap(f2)
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink { _ in
        print("\(Thread.current): completed")
    } receiveValue: { value in
        print("\(Thread.current): sink() value = \(value)")
    }
```